# Why is the View-In-Browser plugin to Sublime Text 3 not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am installing Sublime Text 3.2.2 on macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) including the View-In-Browser plugin. Everything installs as expected using Package Control, but pressing any key combination fails to load the requested browser. There is no apparent effect at all. There are no error messages in the Console. It fills like the keyboard isn't being read, but other key combinations work.

View-In-Browser User key bindings are;

```
[
 { "keys": [ "alt+1" ], "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "/firefox" } },
 { "keys": [ "alt+2" ], "command": "view-in-browser", "args": { "browser": "/chrome" } },
 { "keys": [ "alt+3" ], "command": "view-in-browser", "args": { "browser": "/safari" } },
 { "keys": [ "alt+4" ], "command": "view-in-browser", "args": { "browser": "/opera" } }
]
```

View-In-Browser package user settings are:

```
{
"posix": {
    "darwin": {
        "firefox": "open -a \"/Programs/Firefox.app\"",
        "safari": "open -a \"/Applications/Safari.app\"",
        "chrome": "open -a \"/Programs/Chrome.app\"",
        "opera": "open -a \"/Programs/Opera.app\""
    }
},

"browser": "firefox"
```

}

Things I have tried with no luck:

Read the code many times,  but it always looks good to me. Maybe I have a blind-eye for some syntax error? Do these settings look OK?
Uninstalled and reinstalled the View-In-Browser plugin;
Uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox Developer Edition app;
Reviewed View-In-Browser's github change log for OS compatibility - no comments.
Uninstalled and manually reinstalled the View-In-Browser plugin;
Scanned StackOverflow Sublime-text-plugin for view-in-browser

Are there any known conflicts between View-In-Browser and other plugin packages? Any ideas of other ways to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The paths to the browsers are wrong. All *should* be located in `/Applications`, not `/Programs`. For Firefox, use this setting:

```json
"firefox": "open -a \"/Applications/Firefox.app\"",
```

Do the same for Chrome and Opera if you plan on using them for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's just a personal thing, I don't like to mix my working programs with all the consumere